# How to pass data from Django template (after submission) to DRF API without using a model?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a form in my template which allows a user to upload an image. Once the image is uploaded and submitted, it gets stored in a specified directory (not 'media'). **Note: The image is not stored in a Django model since I didn't create one (don't need it).**

After doing so, I need to create an API using the Django Rest Framework. When calling the API URL, I intend to display that stored image name.

The result will look like this:

```
{"image_name" : <'stored_image_name_after_form_submission'>}
```

This is what I had done so far:

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

#code for uploading an image
def upload(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['image']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT)
        image_path = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)  #name of the image file
        messages.success(request, 'Uploaded The Image.')

    return render(request, "template/upload.html")

class API(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        #API code comes here.
```

The thing is, I can't seem to visualize how to create the API since I am fairly new to it. How can I capture the image name after the form submission and present it in my API view? Can someone explain how it works and what I should do to meet the requirement? Million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if you just want the name of the file to be captured and sent to the `API`, use `session` `variable` for that.

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PRIVATE_STORAGE_ROOT)
request.session['image_name'] = uploaded_file.name
image_path = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
```

and in API

```
def get(self, request):
    image_name = request.session.get('image_name', None)
```

you can remove the name from the `session` once you are done with it

```
del request.session['image_name']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I delete the session within my API code?

Comment: Just asking, what happens if I keep the session?

Comment: Cool. If you don't mind, there's something else on my mind. Suppose if a client has a separate front-end interface for uploading images. I need to supply an API url to them. Is there a way to make the process dynamic since I wouldn't know their field attribute names in HTML. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, I will. But what exactly am I supposed to search for? I've searched for a dynamic process of post requests and DRF online but couldn't find much.

Comment: how to get and pass data to a different frontend using django drf

Comment: Hey, so sorry. The connection got timed off for some reason. I will mark it. I'm still confused about why did you type: 'request.session['image_name'] = uploaded_file.name' instead of the other way around. Care to explain?

Comment: because you are saving it to session, when you are taking it from session it would be other way around. hope you understand it now

Comment: Yes! You just helped me a ton. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any other way to capture data in DRF without using this session technique?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your code in post method, which will get all the data from the template form

```
class API(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # get the data
        data = request.data
        print(data)

        # your logic
        pass
```

Comment: Can you give a clearer demonstration? I am still confused by your answer.